# How to use the p-selectButton of primeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I want use p-selectButton of the PrimeNg . I need to know how would I identify that what button is selected out of the options provided in it . There is a options field in this component which takes data as value and display . Also when I see the selectButtonModule of prime Ng I see that there is a OnChange event Emitter but not aware how to use it .

I have used the OnChange event emitter to see what value is emitted but it logs into the console as undefined

Comment: Share your code. Try $event.value.

Comment: `<p-selectButton class="ois-pills" [options]="options" (onChange)="pillChange($event)" [formControl]="pillsFormControl"></p-selectButton>
`   I need to get the information as what pill has been selected by the user . The options object is an interface which contains label and value .